# Проверка размера папки

Tags: c#

Как с помощью этого метода, проверить размер папки?

```
string Path = @"C:\FlSdutio\"; // эту папку проверить
public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d)
{
  long Size = 0;
  // Add file sizes.
  FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
  foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
  {
    Size += fi.Length;
  }
  // Add subdirectory sizes.
  DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
  foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis)
  {
    Size += DirSize(di);
  }
  return(Size);
}
```

Нужно сделать проверку если папка превышает 100МБ то удалить её.
Как сделать проверку?

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, чем Вас не устраивает приведенный код, и какие проблемы со сравнением результата функции и ста миллионов?

Comment: @Igor, Дело просто в том, что я не знаю как проверить размер папки), с этим методом,реализацию не могу понять, поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string path = @"C:\FlSdutio\";
if (DirSize(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path)) > 100000000)
  System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

Если Вас не интересует действительный размер папки, а только - превышает ли он 100 МБ, передавайте в `DirSize` вторым параметром интересующий Вас размер и выходите из функции, как только `Size` его превысит.

```
public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d, long aLimit = 0)
{
  long Size = 0;
  // Add file sizes.
  FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
  foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
  {
    Size += fi.Length;
    if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
      return Size;
  }
  // Add subdirectory sizes.
  DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
  foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dis)
  {
    Size += DirSize(di, aLimit);
    if (aLimit > 0 && Size > aLimit)
      return Size;
  }
  return(Size);
}

string path = @"C:\FlSdutio\";
long oneHundredMeg = 100000000;
if (DirSize(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path), oneHundredMeg) > oneHundredMeg)
  System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

Comment: @ArteS Попробуйте сформулировать вопросы еще раз. Каким циклом? Что в коде вопроса будет потреблять память?

Answer (score 3):

Нашел еще вот такое решение:

Добавляем Microsoft Scripting Runtime и используем:

```
Scripting.FileSystemObject fso = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
Scripting.Folder folder = fso.GetFolder([folder path]);
Int64 dirSize = (Int64)folder.Size;
```